# How to convert QByteArray to a byte string?

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a `QByteArray` object with 256 bytes inside of it. However, when I try to convert it to a byte string (`std::string`), it comes up with a length of 0 to 256. It is very inconsistent with how long the string is, but there are always 256 bytes in the array. This data is encrypted and as such I expect a 256-character garbage output, but instead I am getting a random number of bytes.

Here is the code I used to try to convert it:

```cpp
// Fills array with 256 bytes (I have tried read(256) and got the same random output)
QByteArray byteRecv = socket->read(2048);
// Gives out random garbage (not the 256-character garbage that I need)
string recv = byteRecv.constData();
```

The `socket` object is a `QTcpSocket*` if it's necessary to know.

Is there any way I can get an exact representation of what's in the array? I have tried converting it to a `QString` and using the `QByteArray::toStdString()` method, but neither of those worked to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QByteArray::constData()` member function returns a raw pointer `const char*`. The [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::string` from a raw pointer

```
std::string(const char* s);
```

constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the **null-terminated** character string pointed to by `s`. The length of the string is determined by the **first** null character. If `s` does not point to such a string, the behaviour is undefined.

Your buffer is not a null-terminated string and can contain null characters in the middle. So you should use another constructor

```
std::string(const char* s, std::size_type count);
```

that constructs the string with the first `count` characters of character string pointed to by `s`.

That is:

```
std::string recv(byteRecv.constData(), 256);
```

---

For a collection of raw bytes, `std::vector` might be a better choice. You can construct it from two pointers:

```
std::vector<char> recv(byteRecv.constData(), byteRecv.constData() + 256);
```